# How to scroll X while scrolling Y in ReactJS and Framer motion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, css-animations, framer-motion, framerjs

How to scroll x on a div while the user keeps scrolling on the Y axis.

I want to recreate the **"Our Work"** section on https://nifty-template.webflow.io/ using ReactJS and Framer Motion.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Py8NB.png)

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if the site is still 'scrolling' down on the Y axis, and that that value is simply just transposed to a fake 'X' axis meter and animation that syncs up to it.

The page is not *actually* moving scroll X as such, so you'd need to do something similar. The accessibility implications of this might not be good however.